# {styler} warning/error 'permission denied' - how to fix?

Tags: r, ubuntu, tidyverse, r-styler

**Setting:**
I'm using Rstudio (2021.09.1.372, Ghost Orchid) on Ubuntu (18.04.6).

I'm trying to use the [{styler} package](https://github.com/r-lib/styler) in it (1.6.2)

**Problem:**
When I run the addin "style active file", I get the following:

```
> styler:::style_active_file()
Using style transformers `styler::tidyverse_style()`
There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

It seemed excessive to get 26 warnings when I should get none.

When I typed "warnings()" It gives the following style of error, (user name replaced with ):

```
24: In file.create(.) :
  cannot create file '/home/<username>/.cache/R/R.cache/styler/1.6.2/794e937fec743117749ff91168b080b2.Rcache', reason 'Permission denied'
25: In file.create(.) :
  cannot create file '/home/<username>/.cache/R/R.cache/styler/1.6.2/1814394756134e6409ffa7a989012fb1.Rcache', reason 'Permission denied'
26: In file.create(.) :
  cannot create file '/home/<username>/.cache/R/R.cache/styler/1.6.2/d1cf21420a8a356674775e8f5b28265b.Rcache', reason 'Permission denied'
```

This tells me that an essential part of how this works isn't working.

**Questions:**

- **What is the source of the problem?**  I run rstudio with user permissions, but do I need to "sudo" it? That doesn't seem like the right answer.  Are files locked in the wrong place?
- **How do I properly resolve this problem?**

---

Edit: I filed a bug report on [GitHub](https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/871).

Comment: The `file.create` function is used in [`styler::cache_write`](https://github.com/r-lib/styler/blob/6936ff7b83d3ef2190da8d1b1c041ded9d37b69f/R/utils-cache.R#L173-L179), with no checking to ensure that the return from [`get_cache_dir()`](https://github.com/r-lib/styler/blob/6936ff7b83d3ef2190da8d1b1c041ded9d37b69f/R/utils-cache.R#L197-L199) *exists*. As such, I suggest this should be a [bug report](https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/new) to the devs.

Comment: In the interim, try `dir.create("/home/<username>/.cache/R/R.cache/styler/1.6.2/", recursive=TRUE)` and rerun your first code.

Comment: or, turn off the cache altogether if you can't create the directory, or check if you can supply a custom cache directory where you have write permissions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @r2evans, you led me to be able to work it out.

I tried your suggestion:

```
dir.create("/home/<username>/.cache/R/R.cache/styler/1.6.2/", recursive=TRUE)
```

It already exists.  It is owned by root, not by my username.

So then I went the .cache, then did this at the command line:

```
sudo chown -R <username> R
```

And when I rerun the styler command then I get no warnings.